# Apache Cassandra Driver for PHP 7.3 on Windows 10, With Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, cassandra, windows-10, php-7.3, cassandra-php-driver

I want to use **Apache Cassandra** No-SQL with Laravel 5.8 on windows 10 operating system.

Currently I am having PHP 7.3 installed on windows, but i am not able to find *Apache Cassandra* PHP driver for windows. Where can I get Apache Cassandra PHP 7.3 driver for windows.

Also is there any Laravel Wrapper/package available for Laravel 5.8 ?

Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/php-driver/1.2/building/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link of Cassandra PHP drivers for windows "https://downloads.datastax.com/php-driver/windows/cassandra/" but currently there is no compatible version of Cassandra driver for php7.3! Because of covid situation there is no exact date of releasing new version and it's remained on maintenance mode.